# Converting a string which represents binary to binary python

Tags: python, binary

I can't quite find a solution for this.

Basically what I've done so far is created a string which represents the binary version of x amount of characters padded to show all 8 bits.

E.g. if x = 2 then I have 0101100110010001 so 8 digits in total. Now I have 2 strings of the same length which I want to XOR together, but python keeps thinking it's a string instead of binary. If I use bin() then it throws a wobbly thinking it's a string which it is. So if I cast to an int it then removes the leading 0's.

So I've already got the binary representation of what I'm after, I just need to let python know it's binary, any suggestions?

The current function I'm using to create my binary string is here

```
for i in origAsci:
    origBin = origBin + '{0:08b}'.format(i)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you just xor the ints together, then pad zeros on the left

Comment: >>> bin(22929)     prints    '0b101100110010001', you need 0b in front of it

Comment: get an `int` from a bitstring do `int('010101010', 2)`

Answer (score 11):

Use Python's int() function to convert the string to an integer. Use 2 for the base parameter since binary uses base 2:

```
binary_str = '10010110' # Binary string
num = int(binary_str, 2)
# Output: 150
```

Next, use the bin() function to convert the integer to binary:

```
binary_num = bin(num)
# Output: 0b10010110
```